# Rotating PDFContentByte Overlay Content

Tags: java, itext

I have created a watermark text that is vertically centered.

This is the line I used

PdfPatternPainter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
   string,  x, y, -90);

What i want to do now is to make the watermark diagonal. changing the angle value will make it diagonal, but then its x,y position is not centered anymore.

this is my current method

```
public static void createWaterMarkPDF(ArrayList<String> watermark, PdfReader reader, PdfStamper stamper) throws Exception {
   Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(1);
    final float WATERMARK_PAGE_ANGLE = 270;

    BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    PdfPatternPainter painter = stamper.getOverContent(1).createPattern(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
    painter.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(192, 192, 192));

    int FONT_SIZE = 80;
    painter.beginText();
    painter.setTextRenderingMode(PdfPatternPainter.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
    painter.setFontAndSize(font, FONT_SIZE);

    for (int i=0; i<watermark.size(); i++) {
        String string = watermark.get(i);
        // Values are opposite since we are doing a vertical alignment angle
        float width = font.getAscentPoint(string, FONT_SIZE) + font.getDescentPoint(string, FONT_SIZE);
        float height = painter.getEffectiveStringWidth(string, true);

        float x = (pageSize.getWidth() - width) / 2;

        if (i == 0)
            x += (width * 3);
        else if (i == 2)
            x -= (width * 3);

        painter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            string,  x, 
            Util.transformY(pageSize, (pageSize.getHeight() - height) / 2),
            WATERMARK_PAGE_ANGLE);

    }

    painter.endText();

    // Transparency of watermark
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.1f);

    for (int i=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i>0; i--) {
        Rectangle thisPageSize = reader.getPageSize(i);
        PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        overContent.setColorFill(new PatternColor(painter));
        overContent.setGState(state);
        overContent.rectangle(thisPageSize.getLeft(), thisPageSize.getBottom(), thisPageSize.getWidth(), thisPageSize.getHeight());
        overContent.fill();
    }
}
```

it draws vertical lines and centered. watermark is an ArrayList. you can add 3 strings.

if i change the angle to , say 300 (or -60) to make it diagonal, the positioning is whacked. do i need to use an AffineTransform here? although i already tried, didnt work for me unless i lacked something here?

Comment: What do you mean by *"its x,y position is not centered anymore"*? Can you show some example code work which your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: hi mkl, i will reply back tomorrow with since i will be off now. what im looking at is having 3 lines of watermark centered diagonally. i cannot get the correct x,y  position for the 1st and 3rd line. 2nd line is ok using readerPageSize.getWidth() / 2 and readerPageSize.getHeight() / 2 as x, y. i will post my code tomorrow.

Comment: hi mkl i updated and placed my code in the post

Comment: What does `Util.transformY` do?

Comment: ah sorry. forgot. it's just my custom method to convert the y position to pdf point origin since my y value is from upper left origin.

Comment: i have something  float x = (pageSize.getWidth()) / 2; float y = (pageSize.getHeight()) / 2; and changing to Element.ALIGN_CENTER and replacing Util.transformY with the y variable. but im not quite sure if the result is satisfying in that it is not vertically centered when diagonal for the 1st and 3rd line. what do you think?

Comment: *"it is not vertically centered when diagonal for the 1st and 3rd line"* - For the first and third line you have code to respectively increase or decrease the `x` value. For vertical text this suffices but otherwise you also have to similarly increase or decrease the `y` value.